# confusion with php function resulting in error on different server

Tags: php, html, scope

i have problem which i dont know how to solved, this is a snapshot of my php script.

```
    foreach($result as $row){
            $Admin [] = array('id'=>$row['id'],'username' => $row['username'], 'email' => $row['email'], 'password'=>$row['password']);
        }

        include 'view_admins.php';
```

and this is part of the `view_admins.php` thats relevent to my question

```
    <article id="admins">//html tag
    <?php 

    foreach($Admin as $admins)://this is line 75

    ?>

        <form action="" method="post" >
            <div>
            <p><tr><td><p><?php htmlout($admins['username']); ?></p></td><td>
            <input type="hidden" align="center" name="id" value="<?php echo $admins['id'];?>"></td><td>

            <input type="submit" name="action" value="edit">
            <input type="submit" name="action" value="delete"></p></td></tr>

            </div>
        </form>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </article>
```

when this code runs it produces a "`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/a2516093/public_html/connect/view_admins.php on line 75`"

my confusion is this code runs perfectly fine on my localhost however when uploaded to my host it produces the above mentioned Warning, can someone please tell me what could be causing the problem, im still learning php programming so any help would be highly appreciated.

To my understanding `$Admin` should be visible in `view_admins.php`, correct me if im wrong. Thank you

Comment: Seems you may be fetching data from a database, does the database information exist on the server?

Comment: yes it exists @AnthonyForloney

Comment: @Sello - check that you're querying the database properly; what are the return values from your database connection and the query? What are the permissions from the database user you're using?

Comment: What does `var_dump($Admin)` show you?

Comment: at least get in the habit of declaring things, have a `$Admin = array();` on top

Comment: @DevZer0 on top where?

Comment: before `foreach($result as $row){` line

Comment: @tlenss is shows me `NULL`. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying to `foreach()` your direct results you got from `mysql_query()`.

You cannot do this. You need to use `mysql_fetch_array()` or `mysql_fetch_assoc();` to define your rows.

An example:

```
$result = mysql_query("Your query");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     $Admin [] = array('id'=>$row['id'],'username' => $row['username'], 'email' => $row['email'], 'password'=>$row['password']);
}
```

The reason your earlier code worked could be because of some automagic configuration settings that fixed the invalid code. Could also be a MySQL plugin that automatically fetched the right attributes while you normally have to do this manually.

Comment: :) hehehe thank you, produces correct results, so my mistake was to take data directly from mysqli_query() i see.

Comment: Exactly! Glad I could help :-).

Comment: @BjornSchijff if i may is there a way to disable these feautures to fix invalid code?i mean i am learning i dont want to write incorrect code thinking its correct because of this fixing feature, only to find out later on another that its incorrect.

Comment: You can use the default production configuration from PHP, MySQL and Apache to prevent any weird functionality. It's also suggested you use the latest versions of all of these platforms in order to get the most reliable feedback (functions that may have been removed in newer version and things like that.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your first line `foreach($result as $row){` Data may not be coming there.

Just `print_r($result);` before `foreach($result as $row){` and see any data is there.

To remove the error check before foreach :

```
<article id="admins">//html tag
<?php 
if(!empty($Admin)){
foreach($Admin as $admins)://this is line 75

?>

    <form action="" method="post" >
        <div>
        <p><tr><td><p><?php htmlout($admins['username']); ?></p></td><td>
        <input type="hidden" align="center" name="id" value="<?php echo $admins['id'];?>"></td><td>

        <input type="submit" name="action" value="edit">
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="delete"></p></td></tr>

        </div>
    </form>
    <?php endforeach; 
    }
    else{ echo "No data found !";}
    ?>
    </article>
```